# Adobe after effects showing green background with nothing every time I import hd videos 

Tags: after-effects, editing

I want to make a project about my country by combining various hyperlapse videos and adding some graphical kinetic topography to them. But every time I import a video, it appears full green...nothinge happens but the workplace appears full green. It does not happen with low quality videos like 240p,but happens with the 1080p ones. Please help!!!!!I have very less days to finish this project. (P.S.- I am a mediocre beginner)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOoZL.jpg)

Comment: Are those videos opening normally in video-players?

Comment: Yes they are opening normally in windows media player @Shultc

Answer (score 1):

It should be problem with codec. Found two solutions:

- [First](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/1029541) — recompile footage to different codec.
- [Second](https://forums.creativecow.net/docs/forums/post.php?forumid=2&postid=1031631&univpostid=1031631&pview=t) — try to install software with codecs.Like Auicktime. Or if it will not help, some codeck pack.

Comment: I typically re-render videos I can't edit as h.264/mp4 using Adobe encoder